# Link to kivy with PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

I am using Windows 10, Python v3.6.4, and kivy v1.10.0. I am trying to get the simple "Hello World" routine (from https://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html) to work in PyCharm.

I carefully followed the kivy instructions and when I call python from the command line it executes perfectly.  From PyCharm it chokes on getting at least one library. I've seen the responses to "How do I import modules in pycharm?" and while the problem seems similar, I don't know what module is missing.

I suspect that I have not set up the venv libraries correctly.  The errors I get are:

```
"F:\Users\Athena\My Documents\Python\kivy1\venv1\Scripts\python.exe" "F:/Users/Athena/My Documents/Python/kivy1/Kivy1.py"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Athena\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-02-04_40.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\Athena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Athena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_sdl2.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.core.text._text_sdl2 import (_SurfaceContainer, _get_extents,

pil - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
  File "C:\Users\Athena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Users\Athena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_pil.py", line 7, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to set project interpreter in the setting option of pycharm and set to anaconda if you are using anaconda and you can install different packages from the anaconda prompt and if you are using system interpreter then you can use command prompt to do so,after installing required packages go to pycharm and create your project.

Comment: I'm not using Anaconda, so I read your advice as "If you are using system interpreter then you can use the command prompt to do so."  I'm reading the last part to say, "After that's done, go ahead and use PyCharm." 
I'm confused by "use the command prompt to do so".  Is there an option in PyCharm to use the command prompt?  I'm afraid I am misunderstanding your reply...

Answer (score 0):

From File in PyCharm select Settings then Project Interpreter.  Add an Interpreter that points to instance of Python that you have added kivy to.